# Are there only two ways to create new objects in C++? (using and without using the `new` keyword)

Tags: c++, oop

Unless I'm mistaken,

`Rectangle rect(3,4);` which calls Rectangle's constructor with 3 and 4 as arguments, but does not assign the created object to pointer or reference or variable or anything.

and

`Rectangle* rect = new Rectangle(3,4);` creates an object and a pointer to that object (`new` always returns a pointer, which is why the type is a pointer to rectangle and not just rectangle. I think.)

Other than those two ways, is there any way to create and object? And am I misunderstanding anything about object initialization?

Edit: sorry, typo, rect is a variable, but it isn't a pointer or reference.

Comment: You really should spend *weeks* (and even *months*) to read more about C++; it is a *difficult* language. Read [this book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/); your question is really too broad, and StackOverflow is not a "teach me C++" forum

Comment: read about stack vs heap to get the difference.

Comment: "*does not assign the created object to pointer or reference or **variable** or anything.*" What is `rect` if it is not a variable?

Comment: In practice, prefer [C++ smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for the response. I've actually been reading Bjarne Stroustrup's A Tour of C++, but I was just hoping for clarification. I noticed my post was received really negatively, if possible could you (or anyone) tell me what I did wrong? I thought I provided enough example and explained myself but now I'm not sure

Comment: @NicolBolas ahh right, sorry that was a slight typo on my part, I understand what variables are haha. Thank you!

Comment: C++ [move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible)  semantics is a *difficult* concept, even  for me (who coded many dozen of thousands of C++ lines of code)

Comment: There are other very obscure ways of creating objects. But it's not clear what you mean by "Am I misunderstanding anything about object initialization?" What is the thing you think you're misunderstanding?

Comment: C++ has a very steep learning curve and it takes a lot of experience to write good and safe code + all the tooling that comes with it - build systems etc. (CMake, premake, many other fancy tools) - many years of learning. 

Recommended reading:
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines
https://gist.github.com/bkaradzic/2e39896bc7d8c34e042b

Comment: You can always try to learn Rust instead of C++. Instead of following best practices, Rust forces you to write safe code. On the other hand, C++ doesn't care how you write your code and it doesn't check if you use smart pointers or not. In certain areas (e.g. game hacking/modding) this is helpful.

Comment: @Konrad thank you for the response, I'll make sure to start reading those two guidelines! I took a look at Rust, and I find what you said very interesting! How is it that in game hacking/modding, being able to not use smart pointers is useful?

Comment: @JamesRonald I think the reason why it was negatively received is because there's a fundamental misunderstanding of what C++ promises when it comes to objects and memory; and what new actually does.  Both of your examples result in a chunk of memory being allocated; and you can obtain both the pointer and reference for either one (*rectPointer; &rectObj) .  The only significant difference the language promises between the two is the lifetime of the memory.

Comment: @Konrad neither of those are in the c++ standard.  Don't disagree that every implementation of c++ (that I know of) does indeed use those; but the language itself doesn't require it.

Comment: @JamesRonald Rust makes it harder to work with raw memory directly (you have to wrap most of the things in `unsafe {}` if you want to do such low-level things). Rust's compiler will check if what you're trying to do is potentially dangerous and your code won't compile without wrapping it in `unsafe {}`. C++ is a more libertarian language and you can do what you want really and your code will still compile. In rust by default, you use smart pointers.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are more ways to create new objects in C++.

From the C++ 17 standard (intro.object/1):

> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created.

Examples:

```
struct Rectangle {
    Rectangle(int x, int y);
    int x, y;
};

Rectangle rect(3,4); // object created by definition. Object has static storage duration

void fun() {
    Rectangle rect(3,4); // object created by definition. Object has automatic storage duration


    new Rectangle(3,4); // object created by new expression Object has dynamic storage duration. Note, it is possible to create object without assigning it to any pointer or reference
}

int temp() {
    return Rectangle(1, 2).x; // temporary object created with automatic storage duration
                              // this is just an example and it is not the only way to create temporary object
}

// Following code can be skipped if you don't know about unions yet
struct A {
    int x;
};

union B {
 A a;
 int z;
};

void test() {
    B b;
    b.a.x = 5; // Creates b.a object.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to create an object, listed in [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object):

> An object is created by **a definition**, by **a new-expression**, when implicitly **changing the active member of a union**, or when a **temporary object is created**. [...]

<sup>bold mine</sup>